# Add slide animation to horizontal scroll system

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollview

I coded a simple horizontal scroll system. At JSFIDDLE you can find an example of my work : http://jsfiddle.net/marcus_derem/qn603h8b/133/

**What do I want to achieve?**
I scroll to a containers child with this:

```
document.getElementById(target_subpage_id).scrollIntoView(false);
```

I can not use this with options to turn on animations, because the Browser SAFARI doesn't support this. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

**My Question:**
How to add a slide animation to the system on JSFIDDLE? Or have I to rewrite the mechanics?

~Thanks in advance Markus.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use javascript for any of this. Like for your current question url fragments would accomplish the same thing and work everywhere, like if you change your second button to an `a` anchor and make it just `<a href="#pss_grades">PAGE 2</a>` and change your css from `button` to `a` it would look the same and accomplish the same goal with no js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css for that:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

But then again, [browser support for that isn't that great either](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior).

There's other methods though. Just read this page for a great overview: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

```
// Scroll to specific values
// scrollTo is the same
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth'
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll to a certain element
document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```